# Automatic field reset MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to automatically reset a field in a table.

I have a database table named `USER` and fields `ID`, `NAME` and `LIMIT`. Every month I need to automatically reset the value in the field `LIMIT` to 0. Is this possible?

Comment: `update mytable set limit = 0`, put it in a cron job or a scheduler?

Comment: There may be a language barrier.

Comment: By the way `LIMIT` is probably not the best name for a field as it's a reserved word... if you can come up with something that's as descriptive but not a reserved word it would be better.

Answer (score 4):

[MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) may be the answer.